# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class linearlayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I use below code to create dialog with checkbox like that:
[image]
Create:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        LayoutInflater adbInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        LinearLayout eulaLayout = (LinearLayout) adbInflater.inflate(R.layout.checkbox, null);
        dontShowAgain = (CheckBox)eulaLayout.findViewById(R.id.skip);
```

Layout of checbox.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <CheckBox 
        android:text="Do not show again" 
        android:id="@+id/skip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    </CheckBox>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make `<linearlayout` to `<Linearlayout`

Comment: you forgot to give width to your linearlayout in checkbox.xml

Comment: post ur complete logcat ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a nested "caused by" exception that would give you more specific reasons for the failure.

But do mind your capitalization. There's no `linearlayout` but there's `LinearLayout`. The same applies to `CheckBox`.

Also your `LinearLayout` will need a `layout_width`.